Member "length" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256
This is my Smart contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract BankAccount {
    event Deposit(
        address indexed user,
        uint indexed accountId,
        uint value,
        uint timestamp
    );
    event WithdrawRequested(
        address indexed user,
        uint indexed accountId,
        uint indexed withdrawId,
        uint amout,
        uint timestamp
    );
    event Withdraw(uint indexed withdrawId, uint timestamp);
    event AccountCreated(address[] owners, uint indexed id, uint timestamp);

    struct WithdrawRequest {
        address user; // who request the withdraw
        address amount;
        uint approvals; // check to determine if the the withdraw is approved
        mapping(address => bool) ownerApproved;
        bool approved;
    }

    struct Account {
        address[] owners;
        uint balance;
        mapping(uint => WithdrawRequest) withdrawRequests; // uint is going to be the id of the withdraw request
    }

    
    mapping(uint => Account) accounts;
    mapping(address => uint) userAccounts; // store the accounts that the users own

    uint nextAccountId; // every time we create an account we increment the id
    uint nextWithdrawId; // every time we request a withdraw we increment the id

    modifier accountOwnership(uint accountId) {

        bool isOwner;
        for (uint idx; idx < accounts[accountId].owners.length; idx++) {
            if (accounts[accountId].owners[idx] == msg.sender) {
            isOwner = true;
            break;
            }
        }
        require(isOwner, "You are not the Owner");
        _;
    }

    function deposit(uint accountId) external payable accountOwnership(accountId) {

        accounts[accountId].balance += msg.value;
    }
    

    modifier validOwner(address[] calldata owners) {
        require(owners.length <= 4, "Max is 4 owners per account");

        for (uint i ; i < owners.length ; i++) {
            for (uint j = i + 1 ; j < owners.length; j++) {
                if (owners[i] == owners[j]) {
                    revert("No Duplicate Owners");
                }
            }
        }
        
        _;
    }
    
    function createAccount(address[] calldata otherOwners) external  validOwner(otherOwners){
        address[] memory owners = new address[](otherOwners.length + 1);
        owners[otherOwners.length] = msg.sender;

        uint id = nextAccountId;

        // this for loop just check if each user had max 3 account 
        // if not the are allowed to create one, if yes we will revert the operation
        for (uint idx ; idx < owners.length; idx++) {
            if (idx < owners.length - 1) {
                owners[idx] = otherOwners[idx];
            }

            if (userAccounts[owners[idx]].length >= 3) {
                revert("Each User has 3 account max");
            }
            userAccounts[owners[idx]].push(id);
        }
        accounts[id].owners = owners;
        nextAccountId++;
        emit AccountCreated(owners, id, block.timestamp);
    }

    modifier sufficientBalance(uint accountId, uint amount) {
        require(accounts[accountId].balance >= amount, "Not enough Balance");
        _;
    }

    function requestWithdraw(uint accountId, uint amount) external accountOwnership(accountId) sufficientBalance(accountId, amount){
        uint id = nextWithdrawId;
        WithdrawRequest storage request = accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[id];
        request.user = msg.sender;
        request.amount = amount;
        nextWithdrawId++;
        emit WithdrawRequested(msg.sender, accountId, id, amount, block.timestamp);
    }

    modifier canApprove(uint accountId, uint withdrawId) {
        require(!accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId].approved, "This is already approved");
        require(accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId].user != msg.sender, "You are the user , can't approved");
        require(accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId].user != address(0), "this request doesn't exist");
        require(!accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId].ownerApproved[msg.sender], "you are already aproved");
        _;
    }

    function approveWithdraw(uint accountId, uint withdrawId) external accountOwnership(accountId) canApprove(accountId, withdrawId) {
        WithdrawRequest storage request = accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId];
        request.approvals++;
        request.ownerApproved[msg.sender] = true;

        if (request.approvals == accounts[accountId].owners.length - 1) {
            request.approved = true;
        }
    }


    modifier withdrawOwnership(uint accountId, uint withdrawId) {
        require(accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId].user ==msg.sender, "You are not the owner of the request");
        require(accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId].approved, "This request is not aproved");
        _;
    }


    function withdraw(uint accountId, uint withdrawId) external withdrawOwnership(accountId, withdrawId) {
        uint amount = accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId].amount;
        require(accounts[accountId].balance >= amount, "not enough money");

        accounts[accountId].balance -= amount;
        delete accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId];
        (bool sent, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value : amount}("");
        require(sent);

        emit Withdraw(withdrawId, block.timestamp);
    }

    function getBalance(uint accountId) public view returns(uint) {
        return accounts[accountId].balance;
    }

    function getOwners(uint accountId) public view returns(address[] memory) {
        return accounts[accountId].owners;
    }

    function getApprovals(uint accountId, uint withdrawId) public view returns (uint) {
        accounts[accountId].withdrawRequests[withdrawId].approvals;
    }


    function getAccounts() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return userAccounts[msg.sender];
    }
}

When I test it it shows me this error:

Member "length" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256.

Checking if user has 3 accounts already

The error occurs on this line:
if (userAccounts[owners[idx]].length >= 3) {


userAccounts is a mapping that takes an address as a key and returns an uint256 as a value. So essentially, userAccounts[owners[idx]] is an uint256 - not an array. And you cannot count the length of the uint256 number.

Based on the context of your code, you might have wanted to simply compare the value of the mapping instead:
if (userAccounts[owners[idx]] >= 3) {

